# getting apache to run python on a mac

Tags: python, apache2, mod-wsgi

So i have a new mac and i'm trying to get it to run apache with mod_python, mod_wsgi, and django. I have a test test.py that simply contains:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
print "Content-type: text/html"
print
print "<html><head>"
print ""
print "</head><body>"
print "Test Page"
print "</body></html>"
```

I've just downloaded xcode4, used macports to install apache, php5, and mod_wsgi via the step provided on these sites: 
http://www.phpied.com/installing-php-and-apache-on-mac-osx-that-was-pretty-easy/ http://heisel.org/blog/2009/09/25/mod-wsgi-mac/

however when i run test.py i just see the file in plain text.  Is there something i'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are expecting WSGI to work like PHP or CGI.  It's somewhat different...

**Problem 1:** That's a Python script, but it's not a WSGI script.  A WSGI script will define an application object ("object" in the strict sense, you don't need a class) which is callable.  See the WSGI PEP ([link](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0333/#the-application-framework-side)), especially "The Application/Framework Side".  The application object will be something like this:

```
def application(env, startresp):
    path = env['PATH_INFO']
    startresp('404 Not Found', [('Content-Type', 'text/plain;charset=utf-8')])
    return ['The page at {!r} was not found'.format(path)]
```

**Problem 2:** The instructions are on how to install Django.  It appears that you aren't using Django.  You'll need to come up with your own `WSGIScriptAlias` line in your Apache configuration.  In the tutorial, it looks like this:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / "/Users/YOUR-USERNAME-HERE/Code/wsgi_apps/local.yourdomain.com.wsgi"
```

But again, you'll have to figure this out for yourself.

**Additional Note:** WSGI was never really written for application developers.  You *can* use it directly, but it's more work for you.  Pick a framework.